# Why does GHC represent recursion in Haskell with recursive binders instead of a fixpoint operator?

Tags: language-design, compiler, haskell, recursion

GHC's [Core data type](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/CoreSynType) represents recursion with recursive binders in the `Let` constructor; as I understand it, all `let` expressions in Haskell are effectively `let rec` expressions. Why does GHC use this method of representing recursion instead of an atomic fixpoint operator?

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: Not sure why GHC specifically does this, but I’ll take a wild guess that it’s just about making it convenient to implement efficiently. If you have `let ones = 1 : ones` you can compile it directly to something like `ones = { push ones; push 1; jump (:) }`, while with the desugared version, `let ones = fix (\ self -> 1 : self)`, you have to recognise that you can inline the lambda and avoid the allocation of a thunk for the application of the lambda to its own application. Presumably it’s also more convenient to work with a *group* of recursive `let` bindings than the same in terms of `fix`.